# Installation of kernel module for I2S Mic fails

Tags: audio, pi-zero-w, kernel, alsa, i2s

I have a I2S mems microphone from adafruit. Now I am following the guide at https://github.com/nejohnson2/rpi-i2s#compile-the-i2s-module

Now after I have mounted the `debugfs` I attempt to look for the given module:

> ```
> $ sudo mount -t debugfs debugs /sys/kernel/debug
> $ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/asoc/platforms
> 3f203000.i2s
> snd-soc-dummy
> ```

However, if I run this code I merely get the following result:

```
sudo mount -t debugfs debugs /sys/kernel/debug
mount: debugs is already mounted or /sys/kernel/debug busy

sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/asoc/platforms
cat: /sys/kernel/debug/asoc/platforms: No such file or directory
```

So am I missing something here. I have another PI which has the same mic and the same wiring and there I can use the microphone without problems.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update**:

I did follow the Adafruit tutorial and in `dmesg` I do see the **Hello world** output from the `my_loader` module.

Here is the output of [`dmesg`](https://gist.github.com/besi/eea8073061e924890638b68d52098746) in a gist.

Comment: It did take more than 15 minutes. The module seemed to compile OK and in `dmesg` the "Hello World" message does show up. It is only today that I did check the `/sys/kernel/debug/asoc/platforms` resource and figured out that there is no `*.i2s` present.

Comment: @Besi  Did you follow official adafruit guide [link]https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test ?  I successfully compiled and installed the module following adafruit guide.

Comment: @jonny789 yes I did follow this tutorial and I could compile the module and it's showing up in dmesg like joan  pointed out.

Comment: @joan I did add a gist of my `dmesg`

Comment: Do you have anything at all inside `/sys/kernel/debug/`? What do you get for `lsof /sys/kernel/debug`?

Comment: I do have `components` `dais` and `snd_rpi_sipmle_card` inside the   `/sys/kernel/debug/asoc` directory.

Comment: @jonny789 I did initially follow the guide but it was updated in November 2019. I'll add an answer outlining procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and did manage to get the MEMS mic working.

Apparently the guide was updated after I did setup my RaspberryPi using the guide which Johnny789 did point out in a comment.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test

> This page (Raspberry Pi Wiring & Test) was last updated on Nov 19, 2019.

In the Adafruit [forum](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=150292#p744812) I did find the relevant information:

> OK, I got this working. The guide page has been updated:
>   https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test.
>   Please try going through it again. You may need to start all the way from a fresh
>   OS image since things may be in a weird state. I used Raspbian Lite
>   2019-04-08 on a Pi Zero w.
>
> The main changes were:
>
> - need to install more packages: `bison`, `flex`, `libssl-dev`
> - the script pauses here, just press enter to continue: `Code coverage for fuzzing (KCOV) [N/y/?] (NEW)`
> - this didn't work but didn't matter: `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/asoc/platforms`

I did not use a fresh OS and did just install it ontop of the old stuff. I did however delete any previous linux-source files along with the i2s-audio folder:

```
cd 
rm -fr linux* # this took quite long
rm -fr rpi-i2s-audio/
```

Also the author mentioned that `/sys/kernel/debug/asoc/platforms` wasn't available either but that it did not matter to get it working.

**Update:**
In order to know which I2S Platform to use you may use the following command:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/asoc/components | uniq
20203000.i2s
snd-soc-dummy
```